# JOGL not rendering

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I developed a simple JOGL rendering a Cube on the screen, followed the same procedure that would work on OpenGL ES 2 from IPhone. but this piece of code does not displaying anything when it is ran.

can someone help to take a browse and point out what is the problem?

Here is my Code

```
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import org.joml.Matrix4f;
import org.joml.Vector3f;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

public class TestScene extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {

    private static final float[] CUBE_POSITIONS = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    };

    private static final short[] INDICIES = {
            0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,//front
            2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5,//right
            7, 6, 4, 6, 5, 4,//back
            7, 4, 3, 3, 4, 0,//right
            6, 7, 2, 7, 3, 2,//top
            0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 5,//bottom
    };

    private GL4 gl;
    private int program;
    private Matrix4f projection = new Matrix4f();
    private Matrix4f viewing = new Matrix4f();
    private Matrix4f translation = new Matrix4f();
    private int projectionIndex;
    private int viewingMatrix;
    private int transIndex;
    private int positionIndex;
    private int vbo;
    private int vio;

    public TestScene() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Testing");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4)));
        final FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(25);
        animator.add(canvas);
        animator.start();
        canvas.addGLEventListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(canvas);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(final GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        gl = drawable.getGL().getGL4();

        try {
            //init program and shader
            final int vertexShader = createShader("/Users/gang_liu/Develop/Java/ideaProject/KLM/JOGL_Studies_1/vertex.glsl", GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            final int fragmentShader = createShader("/Users/gang_liu/Develop/Java/ideaProject/KLM/JOGL_Studies_1/fragment.glsl", GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            program = gl.glCreateProgram();
            gl.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            gl.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
            gl.glLinkProgram(program);

            //generate vbo
            final IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
            gl.glGenBuffers(1, intBuffer);
            vbo = intBuffer.get();
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CUBE_POSITIONS.length * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(CUBE_POSITIONS), GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            intBuffer.flip();

            //generate vio
            gl.glGenBuffers(1, intBuffer);
            vio = intBuffer.get();
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vio);
            gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, INDICIES.length * Buffers.SIZEOF_SHORT, ShortBuffer.wrap(INDICIES), GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            //get program indexes
            positionIndex   = gl.glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
            projectionIndex = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection");
            viewingMatrix   = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "view");
            transIndex      = gl.glGetUniformLocation(program, "trans");

            //init projection matrix;
            final int width = getWidth();
            final int height = getHeight();
            projection.perspective(45.0f, (float)width/height, 1.0f, 100.0f);
            viewing.lookAt(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        } catch (final Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }  

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void display(final GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL4.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glEnable(GL4.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0);
        gl.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL4.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glUseProgram(program);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, false, Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT * 3, 0);

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionIndex, 1, false, FloatBuffer.wrap(projection.get(new float[16])));
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(viewingMatrix, 1, false, FloatBuffer.wrap(viewing.get(new float[16])));
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(transIndex, 1, false, FloatBuffer.wrap(translation.get(new float[16])));

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vio);
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, INDICIES.length, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        gl.glUseProgram(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    }

    private int createShader(final String fileName, final int type) throws IOException {
        final int shaderID = gl.glCreateShader(type);

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        gl.glShaderSource(shaderID, 1, new String[]{sb.toString()}, null, 0);
        gl.glCompileShader(shaderID);
        final IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl.glGetShaderiv(shaderID, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, intBuffer);
        if (intBuffer.get() == gl.GL_FALSE) {
            intBuffer.flip();
            gl.glGetShaderiv(shaderID, gl.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, intBuffer);
            final int logLength = intBuffer.get();
            final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(logLength);
            gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, logLength, null, byteBuffer);
            System.out.println("Filed to compile " +
                (type == GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex shader" : "fragment shader")
                + " shader :\n" + new String(byteBuffer.array()));
         }
        return shaderID;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScene();
    }
}
```

here are the shader files

vertex shader

```
#version 400

uniform lowp mat4 trans;
uniform lowp mat4 view;
uniform lowp mat4 projection;
in lowp vec3 position;
out lowp vec3 out_color;

void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * view * trans * vec4(position, 1.0);
    out_color = position;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 400
in lowp vec3 out_color;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
    fragColor = vec4(out_color, 1.0);
}
```

I know I should calculate uniform matrix in CPU. again, this is just good for debugging.

beside of this problem, I have another question. it seems some opengl functions related of a program like glGetAttribLocation and glGetUniformLocation has program parameter, so does that mean we do not have to call glUseProgram ahead of these function invocations? is that assumption correct? any opinion regarding on this question is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Nitpick: remove the `try/catch(Exception)` from `init`, it doesn't do any error handling and continuing after failing to initialize would be bad (also it doesn't check for OpenGL errors)

Comment: Regarding your last question, only functions that load values such as `glUniformMatrix4fv`, `glUniform1i` or `glUniformBlockBinding` need the program to be bound. `glGetAttribLocation` and `glGetUniformLocation' don't need.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, try catch was added due to reading vertex and fragment shaders from file. you know, java is very robust. I will handle them after this testing code worked.

Comment: @elect, thank for your answer, you have helped me in another post so I have decided to give JOGL a try

Comment: Java is robust, but your code isn't. If you're only catching errors thrown by compiling the shaders, then only put the shaders in the try block. It makes no sense to ignore the exception and continue if an exception is thrown and your shaders are half set up.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, you are right, I will modify this design flaw

Comment: I am glad it helped :). Anyway, I strongly suggest you to take a look to [these samples](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples) in order to learn the last features of opengl

Comment: Anyway, all the program indices are > 0? Can we see the shaders?

Comment: @elect I have updated the post, with shader code. thank you very much

Comment: For the moment, try to comment out for the moment the code relative to the square rendering and the matrix chain. Render just a triangle, as [here](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTriangle/HelloTriangle.java), no indexed array, load just a single identity matrix and check if this works.